# How do I show a div when a drop down is set to "No"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a [form](http://plantdevelopment.com/liners/order-encore-liners-associate) that has the address fields hidden by default. If someone has not ordered before, they change the drop down from Yes to No and the Address field should show up.

The drop down is coded as follows:

```
<label for="have_ordered_before"><span>*Have you ordered from us before?</span>
<select name="have_ordered_before" id="have_ordered_before">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
</label>
```

and the Address div is as follows:

```
<div id="address-info" style="display:none">
 form details go here...
</div>
```

The script I am trying to use is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check_dd() {
    if(document.getElementById('have_ordered_before').value == "Yes") {
        document.getElementById('address-info').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('address-info').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
```

I am open to solutions here and would appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none. And where do you call your check_dd function? I also see no event handlers.

Comment: Because I am open to a jQuery solution as well.

Comment: Seems like adding the handler would work: `<select name="have_ordered_before" id="have_ordered_before" onchange="check_dd()">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you can do in jQuery

```
$(function(){
$('#have_ordered_before').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val == 'Yes')
       $('#address-info').hide();
    else 
      $('#address-info').show();
});
});
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but something is still missing. Please refer to the page and see.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Works perfect now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the event change (in this case **change**, click/keypress are other examples) to the function to check:

```
document.getElementById('have_ordered_before').onchange = check_dd;
```

[I've made you a small example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ws4DX/)

---

If you want jQuery*:

```
$('#have_ordered_before').on('change',check_dd);
```

Or, if you want the whole thing jQuery*:

```
$('#have_ordered_before').on('change',function(){
    $('#address-info').css({display: $(this).val()=='Yes' ? 'none' : 'block' }); 
});
```

[And again, the example](http://jsfiddle.net/y6LFQ/1/)

**Both require a document-ready*

Answer (score 0):

Via jQuery :
use .change()

```
 $('#selectId').change(function(){
     if($('#selectId option:selected').val() == "No"){
         $('#divId').show();
     } else {
         $('#divId').hide();              
     };
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the call to the function:  onchange="check_dd()"